# AS3-Facebook: How do I capture the RawResult for calls like for friends

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, facebook

I am using Flex and with the AS3 libraries. I can make calls etc but when i get values returned in the event, they are in RawResult. I am not sure how to turn that into an arraycollection etc so i can make use of it in flex, or if there is a better way of accessing the data, generally speaking.

tried=

```
var friendsDoc : XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(e.data.rawResult);
                    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
                    var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(friendsDoc);
                    //var testString: String = resultObj.user[0].uuid as String;                    
                    nameText.text = resultObj.user[0].uuid as String;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the rawResult a valid xml string? Then you can use [e4x in AS3](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4#e4x). The `XML` class from AS2 is retained in AS3 as [XMLDocument class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/xml/XMLDocument.html) for backward compatibility. It is recommended to use the e4x enabled [XML](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html) class in AS3.

Using the e4x syntax, your code can be simplified to a couple of lines.

Let's say `rawResult` was

```
<root xmlns="http://some.url">
  <user id="1">
    <uuid>something</uuid>
  </user>
  <user id="2">
    <uuid>something else</uuid>
  </user>
</root>
```

We can parse it like:

```
var friendsDoc:XML = new XML(e.data.rawResult);
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://some.url");
trace(friendsDoc.ns::user[0].ns::uuid);//something
trace(friendsDoc.ns::user[1].ns::@id);//2
trace(friendsDoc.ns::user.(@id == "2").ns::uuid);//something else
```

Comment: The thing is the rawResult is like <fql_query_response list="true" xmlns="..."> <friend_info>  <uid2>  1303529</uid2></friend_info><friend_info><uid2>1303522</uid2></friend_info>. When i try what you say,  i get 'A term is undefined and has no properties'.

Comment: hey mate i tried that and still get the term error, and its pointing to the trace line as the line of error.

Comment: Is there another way besides using xml to get the friends list, ie through an arraycollection or something, or does it have to be parsed?

Comment: Does any other tag than the root (like friend_info or uid) have xmlns declarations? If so, you have to call them with their respective namespaces. See the link in my post http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4#e4x for more info on xml namespaces

Comment: Since the data is an xml string, you have to parse it using xml itself. no other way.